# Meshlab Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation Quality threshold

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I was wondering if anyone could explain in more detail the Quality Threshold value and how this value is used?

The description states: "Quality threshold for penalizing bad shaped faces.The value is in the range [0..1] 0 accept any kind of face (no penalties), 0.5 penalize faces with quality < 0.5, proportionally to their shape"

What does proportionally to their shape mean?

Is there a way to specify the quality by measurement? E.g decimate the mesh by 90%, but within a tolerance of 1mm.
i.e. do not remove a triangle if the decimated mesh will alter the shape by more than 1mm

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

> What does proportionally to their shape mean?

I'm not sure what that means. I have browsed MeshLab source code, but didn't find anything related to shape ([Source](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/blob/master/src/meshlabplugins/filter_meshing/meshfilter.cpp#L850)).

> Is there a way to specify the quality by measurement?

You can specify how to measure quality of a face by using `Filters -> Quality Measure and Computations -> Per Face Quality Function`. But the variables you can use are limited and off the top of my head I cannot think how to achieve what you are looking for.